# Set height of all divs using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set the height of all my divs with class `page` to 100% of the browser window...

I have the following only nothing happens and i get no errors in the console, I'm aware I could do this with jquery only my aim is to do it solely with JS.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('page');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
    elements.style.height = document.getElementsByTagName(window).height;
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName(window)` does not look right. What are you trying to achieve by that? Could it be that you want something like `...height = window.innerHeight + 'px';`?

Comment: Class selectors [use a `.` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html) -- `document.querySelectorAll('.page')`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple different things wrong here:

- You can now use `document.getElementsByClassName`
- You want to use `el` instead of `element` in your forEach block
- Using `window.innerHeight` for the window height

**Solution**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
    el.style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VrdwN/

Comment: Don't just post links to external pages. Include the solution in your post, and **explain** it.

Comment: @Liam No problem, marking as answer would be awesome unless you run into anything else!